# Lazarus. Equivalent to Chr() for Unicode symbols

Tags: delphi, unicode, freepascal, lazarus

Is there any function in freepascal to show the Unicode symbol by its code (e.g. U+1D15E)? Unfortunately `Chr()` works only with ANSI symbols (with codes less than 127). 
I want to use symbols from custom symbolic font and it is very inconvenient to put them into sourcecode directly (they are shown in Lazarus as `?` or something else because they are absent in system fonts).

Comment: `U+1D15E` is a slightly pathological example since `1D15E` is not a word (one hex digit too many).

Comment: @Andreas: Unicode has symbol with code U+1D15E. It is in the group of musical symbols: http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D100.pdf

Comment: I know. I just said it was slightly pathological, which it is, in the sense that it is easier to work with codepoints that fit inside a word, and many applications only work with those.

Comment: @Andreas If that's the code point you want then that's the code point you want.

Comment: @Andreas: U+1D15E is a valid code point. Such designations of code points are not limited to a certain encoding like UTF-16 (to which you seem to refer) or even UTF-8. How this is encoded into a surrogate pair is part of UTF-16. And if FP uses UTF-8 (which would not surprise me), it is encoded as a number of bytes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [this page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d15e/index.htm). I assume that Freepascal either uses UTF-16, in which it becomes a surrogate pair of two WideChars (see table) or UTF-8, in which it becomes a sequence of byte values (see table again).

UTF-8:

```
const
  HalfNoteString = UTF8String(#$F0#$9D#$85#$9E);
```

UTF-16:

```
const
  HalfNoteString = UnicodeString(#$D834#$DD5E);
```

The names of the string types may differ, as I don't know FreePascal very well. Perhaps AnsiString and WideString.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis: Thank you! The first variant works perfectly in Lazarus!

Comment: FPC 2.4.x+ has unicodestring. It doesn't have ansistring with codepages, and unicodestring is not used much in the libraries, but it is there. (since basically it is the old Kylix widestring with minor rearrangements and enhancements in the record)

Answer (score 5):

I have never used Free Pascal, but if I were you, I'd try

```
var
  s: char;
begin
  s := char($222b);                   // Just cast a word
```

or, if the compiler is really stubborn,

```
var
  s: char;
begin
  PWord(@s)^ := $222b;                // Forcibly write a word
```

Comment: Thank you! Both variants work right. Nevertheless, do you know any way to use codepoints that don't fit inside a word (my font has several symbols there)?

Comment: @VIK: I am afraid I don't even know exactly how Delphi handles these... Maybe David knows?

Comment: @VIK: in Delphi's UnicodeString, they are encoded as a ***pair*** of words, called a surrogate pair. How U+1D15E is encoded in UTF-16 (assuming that is actually what Free Pascal uses -- I could imagine that they could just as well use UTF-8 everywhere, where it can be encoded in up to 5 bytes, IIRC), I don't know.

Comment: UTF-16 is indeed a pair of WideChars. That's how you'd want it on Windows. As for Free Pascal I have no idea what the natural Unicode encoding is.

Comment: codepoints are encoded as maximally a pair of widechars. Note that a codepoint is not the same as a character, and that e.g. UTF16 on OS X is typically denormalized (more codepoints for accented chars)

Answer (score 4):

Current unicode status of FPC to my best knowledge

1. The codepage of literals can be set with $codepage http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progsu81.html
2. FPC 2.4.x+ does have unicodestring (since it is +/- Kylix widestring) but only basic routine support. (pos and copy, not routines like format), but the "record" misses the codepage field.
3. Lazarus widgets expect UTF8 in normal ansistrings (D7..D2007 ansistrings without codepage data), and programmers must manually insert conversions if necessary. So on Windows the widgets ARE mostly using unicode (-W) calls, but take ansistrings with UTF8 in it.
4. FPC doesn't follow the utf8 in ansistring scheme , so for some string accepting routines in sysutils, there are special routines in Lazarus that assume UTF8 that call -W variants)
5. FPC ansistring is the system default 1-byte encoding. ansi on Windows, utf8 on most other platforms.
6. Trunk, 2.7.1, provides support for the new D2009+ ansistring (with codepages).
7. There has been no discussion yet how to deal with the default stringtype (e.g. will "string" be utf8string on *nix and unicodestring on Windows, or unicodestring or utf8string everywhere?)
8. Other unicodestring related enhancement (like encoding parameters to tstringlist.savetofile) are not implemented. Likewise for the pseudo objects (like TCharacter which are afaik mostly static)

Update: 2.7.1 has a variable encoding ansistring type, and lazarus has been fixed to keep working. Nothing is really taking advantage from it yet though, e.g. most of the RTL still uses -A calls, and prototypes of sysutils and system procedures that takes strings haven't changed to rawbytestring yet.

Answer (score 3):

I assume the problem is to convert from UCS4 encoding (which is actually a Unicode codepoint number) to UTF16.

In Delphi, you can use `UCS4StringToUnicodeString` function.

**Warning:** Be careful with `UCS4String` type. It is actually a zero-terminated dynamic array, not a string (that means it is zero-based).

```
var
  S1: UCS4String;
  S: string;

begin
  SetLength(S1, 2);
  S1[0]:= UCS4Char($1D15E);
  S1[1]:= UCS4Char(0);
  S:= UCS4StringToUnicodeString(S1);
  ShowMessage(Format('%d, %x, %x', [Length(S), Ord(S[1]), Ord(S[2])]));
end;
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The other answers only get you partway there. This actually works.